# How to pass parameters in HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, post

I created an API KEY using thingSpeak of the page http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html . The page takes two inputs latitude and longitude and provides the location name as the output.

https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=OQHAGOXG1YOYJPZC this is the equivalent address to the web page using the API_KEY.In this I want to pass the inputs (Latitude and Longitude) too.How can I do that.(i.e I want to obtain a link which when executed will give me the page showing the output).

How can i pass the parameters latitude and longitude to this page through the above equivalent address.

Comment: A bit confused. The page https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/... does not work. When it is opened, there is a Google Map API error in console. After input latitude & longitude in page and click "Convert", nothing happens. Do you want to send HTTP request to this page's server? If yes, maybe you need to fix the page first.

Comment: Also, what is the relationship between http://www.latlong.net/... and https://api.thingspeak.com/..? Is there any API document?

Comment: The latlong.net page does not accept parameters from the URL - only from the input box. They pass the parameters to the Google Maps API.

Comment: ohho.anyways thank you i will try some other way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a program like Postman to manually send requests to that endpoint, and you can populate the body too. Using jquery, this is how you would send a POST to that endpoint:

```
var endpoint = https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=OQHAGOXG1YOYJPZC;
var data = new Object();
data.longitude = 50;
data.latitude = 50;
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: endpoint,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (response) {

            }
    });
```

Comment: Can i do this from Arduino?I mean i use a GPS to get latitude nd longitude is it possible to use this query in it?

Comment: youd have to look at what libraries arduino has for making network calls. Im almost certain that there exists something. No, i am certain that there are libraries for making network calls on arduino